# Referencing an Online resource

Tags: bibliographies

There are several questions about referencing a website in a thesis. I am using the following BibTex to reference a website:

```
@online{BoostLibrary,
    title = "{Boost C++ Libraries}",
    url = "http://www.boost.org/",
    urldate = "2015-06-30"
}
```

**PROBLEM:** With the above BibTex, the reference name appears as **`[Boo]`**. However, in my other references (e.g. some research paper), the year also appears in the reference such as, [ACH15]. **So, how can I get the year number visible in the reference name?**

Furthermore, with the above method, I get the following text in the Bibliography, which also does not show the year

```
Boost C++ Libraries. http://www.boost.org/
```

so, how can I get the year visible in the text of Bibliography?

Comment: Which style do you use, do you use biblatex and biber? Or bibtex?

Comment: I am using bibtex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you're using BibTeX and the `alpha` bibliography style. (Please advise if this isn't correct.) Two comments:

- To get the citation call-out to show a two-digit abbreviated form of the publication year, be sure to provide a non-empty `year` field. (The example entry you provided lacks a `year` field.)
- The entry type `@online` is not defined by the `alpha` bibliography style; the type `@online` thus defaults to the catch-all entry type `@misc`, which features a field named `howpublished`. I suggest you use this field for the URL string and rename the field `urldate` to `note`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{hello.bib}
@misc{BoostLibrary,
    author = "Boost",
    year   = 2015,
    title  = "{Boost C++ Libraries}",
    howpublished = "\url{http://www.boost.org/}", 
    note   = "Last accessed 2015-06-30",
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage{url} % for "\url" macro

\begin{document}
\cite{BoostLibrary}
\bibliography{hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case you have written "Boost" as a author name, which seems ok in this particualr case. But, in some other online resources, you can't write author name like this. What should I do in that case. For example, I have to make the reference of this one also `Siren Song of Segmentation. http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jepson/csc2503/
segmentation.pdf`. The url access date is `urldate = "2015-05-04"`.

Comment: @skm - I don't seem to have access to `http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jepson/csc2503`, so I'm afraid I can't determine what might be a good way to proceed for the additional entry you mention.

Comment: Actually, I checked that we can access `http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jepson`, where we can find the name of the professor. So, I have used that name as author's name. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the updated link. I agree that setting `author = "A.D. Jepson and D.J. Fleet"` for the lecture notes in question is the right thing to do.